# Selenium can locate an element, but it seems to be return an empty object, quite unexpected

Tags: javascript, selenium

this one has been bugging me for a while.
I'm trying to locate an element inside a page, with Selenium (bound with Python).
The target element is as follows,

```
<a id="topmenu_adhocQtraditional_Reports" title="" href="javascript:menuGizmo.navigate('Reports','mdiv_topmenu_Reports','topmenu_adhocQtraditional','Adhoc Query Traditional LIMS',function(){sapphire.page.navigate('rc?command=page&amp;page=AdhocQTraditional','Y',null, null, true, document.getElementById('topmenu_adhocQtraditional_Reports'))})" class="menugizmo_link" _menuid="Reports">Adhoc Query Traditional LIMS</a>
```

My problem is, i want to locate the above element inside  tag, Selenium seems to be able to locate it as it does not throw error. However when I try to apply click() method on it, it throws an errror saying 'Not interactable'. And I tried to use is_displayed() method, it returns false. But I'm pretty sure i have waited sufficient time to wait for page loading to complete.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The element is likely not completely visible. You can click on it ignoring visibility check in JavaScript with the `.click()` method on elements

Comment: There may be various reasons for the element to be not intractable. Check if the CSS properties applied (may visible or display: none ) could be interfering with the display-ness of the element.

Comment: hi Ben, could you please elaborate a bit more on the visibikity check？

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use ActionsChain to move to the element first and then click on it using Actions class :

```
const actions = driver.actions();
await actions
.mouse(your web element here) 
.perform();
```

Read more about Actions class with Javascript [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html)

Comment: Second alternative would be scroll down till you think selenium can see that element and then click on it.

Comment: hi i tried the actionchains , it still throws error saying element does not support click method.

Comment: Can you share where you have written click method ?

Comment: driver_LIMS_report = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-id-64"]/a')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver_LIMS_report).click(driver_LIMS_report).perform()

Comment: as indicated above, firstly i tried to grab the element and assigned it to a variable, then tried to apply chain actions. an error is thrown, saying "element not interactable".

Comment: When you manually interact with that element do you have to scroll down to see that object ?

Comment: No need to scroll, but i need to click on it for it to expand and show a dropdown, then move mouse to the desired item, and click again to invoke a page refresh to load an iFrame